# kendoChart with datasource going over the chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I'm creating a stacked bar chart and almost everytime, the bars on my chart are overflowing.

I'm not sure what could be causing this, I found that people had issues with sorting data source in chrome but this is not specific to chrome. Sometime depending on the default sort I set, it would show up correctly, but if I changed the sorting, it would go back to messed up. On top of this, sometime the values are interchanged but if I checked the datasource.data(), it would still be okay.

I tried calling redraw, refresh on the chart, read on the datasource, I'm a bit lost here

Thanks for any help!

http://jsfiddle.net/2mMMC/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var data = {
    data: [{"name":"R-24","series":"Moving","Idle":0,"Moving":1396,"Stopped":0,"count":"0.39"},
           {"name":"R-25","series":"Moving","Idle":0,"Moving":6795,"Stopped":0,"count":"1.89"},
           {"name":"P-24","series":"Moving","Idle":0,"Moving":2622,"Stopped":0,"count":"0.73"},
           {"name":"RF-24","series":"Stopped","Idle":0,"Moving":0,"Stopped":796,"count":"0.22"},
           {"name":"RF-25","series":"Stopped","Idle":0,"Moving":0,"Stopped":27024,"count":"7.51"},
           {"name":"P-24","series":"Stopped","Idle":0,"Moving":0,"Stopped":26430,"count":"7.34"}
          ],
    group: [{
        field: 'series'
    }],
    sort: [{
        field: "series",
        dir: "asc"
    }]
};
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: data,
    series: [{
        field: 'count',
        stack: true,
        type: 'bar'
    }],
    categoryAxis: [{
        field: 'name'
    }],
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "{0}%",
        template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
    }
});
```

});

Comment: I found that that my string value was causing the chart to overflow.
But my values are still interchanged with other rows when I'm sorting

Comment: Same problem for me -- the field for my stacked column was a string. I fixed it by converting the values to floats using `parseFloat()`. Strangely, the problem only happened when using stacked columns. The graph rendered just fine when it wasn't stacked.